# PhantomJS multiple instances

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am scraping a website with phantomjs but I'd like to do this with multiple phantomjs processes in parallel requesting the same url and asking for different information from the page. I intend to offer this as a service using node.js and the child_process module. However, running `phantomjs scraper.js &` multiple times and inspecting my logs I can see that only two phantomjs processes are able to scrape from the website. The other phantomjs processes idle until the other two processes finish. In the logs the phantomjs processes are idling before the onLoadFinished event (that is, only two processes are able to fire this event while the others idle before firing such event). If I bypass the onLoadFinished event (which should fire before scraping the site), the processes do not appear to serialize as before but execute in parallel. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Some sites limit the number of simultaneous connections a single client can make but that doesn't seem to be your use case. Unlike Firefox, there also is no `-no-remote` command line option to say "start a new process instead of opening the URLs in one that already runs". I'm out of ideas.

Comment: if you are just scraping, you could use http://phantomjscloud.com instead of rolling-your-own.  (disclaimer: i wrote it)